# amp-analytics example doesn't fire hits

Tags: analytics, amp-html

I'm trying to start from examples from the `<amp-analytics>` tag, but event by copy/pasting the github example (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/analytics.amp.html), I can't get any analytics hit to be sent, it just fails silently.

The validator doesn't support it yet (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1087), therefore validation errors seem to be 
normal:

```
Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1450396666888
http://localhost:3000/page.html#development=1:22:0 DISALLOWED_TAG amp-analytics
```

However, the example should work. Am I missing something somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Before a few days ago, this component was still expermiental and you had to run : AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-analytics') from the browser's javascript console. The component seems not to be experimental since a few days now so it should work as expected :

1. Add the amp-analytics library : `<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>`
2. Add the amp-analytics tag :

```html
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics2">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-39250300-2"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "default pageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Normaly, you should see the hit being fired.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The feature is not fully implemented yet. Follow https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/871 on github for updates.

Comment: Thanks ! I actually read the thread, but I understood that hits were supposed to be sent (GET only, but sent). I'll follow the discussions there.